# AndroidBillingLibrary ошибка

Tags: android

Помогите пофиксить ошибку. Добавил библиотеку и никак не могу исправить[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Для начала вы должны зайти в SDK manager и скачать api 17**

[image]

---

**Потом правой кнопкой по проекту -> Propeties -> Android, и выбрать**

[image]

Comment: Спасибо. Но не помогает. Попрежнему ошибки в BillingRequest.java b BillingService.java